# how to insert two records at the same time whitout duplicate

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a system in php and sql server 2005, I create a form that has a correlative number, I increment this number with php ej. $i++  but when two people push the button to save this form at the same time, it's created two forms whit the same number in the data base, this is my code:

```
$correlativo=$correlativo+1;
$queryVeri="SELECT * FROM FacturaCabecera WHERE  NumFactura='$correlativo'";
$respVeri=EjecutarlocalFA($queryVeri);
if(count($respVeri)!=0)
{
    $numeroFactura=$numeroFactura+1;
}

INSERT INTO FacturaCuerpo([num_factura])VALUES('$correlativo');
```

to solve this problem, I tried to verify if the correlative number exist in the table, if it exist I increment the number again and insert in the table, this to do not duplicate the number but it doesn't work,¿How can I do? I hope you can help me.

the number correlative has to start in 1 again every six months I don't know if it's posible to have two primary key autoincrement

Comment: Why not have the database do the auto incrementing (IDENTITY column type)?

Comment: You can use instagram's method for generating primary keys, http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

Answer (score 1):

num_factura must be primary key in your database, and you can make this field autoincremental. If you do that you doesn't need $correlativo anymore.

You must have something like this:

```
if(count($raspVeri != 0)) insert();
//insert into FacturaCuerpo ("desc", "qty", "whatever") values ($desc, $qty, $whatever);
```

And let MySql deal with "numFactura". Another advise, try to use PDO. Good luck!

Comment: the number correlative has to start in 1 again every six months I don't know if it's posible to have two primary key autoincrement

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from Instagram's Engineering page for how they deal with their primary keys:

http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

---

### Existing solutions

Many existing solutions to the ID generation problem exist; here are a few we considered:

**Generate IDs in web application**

This approach leaves ID generation entirely up to your application, and not up to the database at all. For example, MongoDB’s ObjectId, which is 12 bytes long and encodes the timestamp as the first component. Another popular approach is to use UUIDs

Pros:

1. Each application thread generates IDs independently, minimizing points of failure and contention for ID generation
2. If you use a timestamp as the first component of the ID, the IDs remain time-sortable

Cons:

1. Generally requires more storage space (96 bits or higher) to make reasonable uniqueness guarantees
2. Some UUID types are completely random and have no natural sort

**Generate IDs through dedicated service**

Ex: Twitter’s Snowflake, a Thrift service that uses Apache ZooKeeper to coordinate nodes and then generates 64-bit unique IDs

Pros:

1. Snowflake IDs are 64-bits, half the size of a UUID
2. Can use time as first component and remain sortable
3. Distributed system that can survive nodes dying

Cons:

1. Would introduce additional complexity and more ‘moving parts’ (ZooKeeper, Snowflake servers) into our architecture

**DB Ticket Servers**

Uses the database’s auto-incrementing abilities to enforce uniqueness. Flickr uses this approach, but with two ticket DBs (one on odd numbers, the other on even) to avoid a single point of failure.

Pros:

1. DBs are well understood and have pretty predictable scaling factors

Cons:

1. Can eventually become a write bottleneck (though Flickr reports that, even at huge scale, it’s not an issue).
2. An additional couple of machines (or EC2 instances) to admin
3. If using a single DB, becomes single point of failure. If using multiple DBs, can no longer guarantee that they are sortable over time.

Of all the approaches above, Twitter’s Snowflake came the closest, but the additional complexity required to run an ID service was a point against it. Instead, we took a conceptually similar approach, but brought it inside PostgreSQL.

### Our solution

Our sharded system consists of several thousand ‘logical’ shards that are mapped in code to far fewer physical shards. Using this approach, we can start with just a few database servers, and eventually move to many more, simply by moving a set of logical shards from one database to another, without having to re-bucket any of our data. We used Postgres’ schemas feature to make this easy to script and administrate.

Schemas (not to be confused with the SQL schema of an individual table) are a logical grouping feature in Postgres. Each Postgres DB can h2have several schemas, each of which can contain one or more tables. Table names must only be unique per-schema, not per-DB, and by default Postgres places everything in a schema named ‘public’.

Each ‘logical’ shard is a Postgres schema in our system, and each sharded table (for example, likes on our photos) exists inside each schema.

We’ve delegated ID creation to each table inside each shard, by using PL/PGSQL, Postgres’ internal programming language, and Postgres’ existing auto-increment functionality.

Each of our IDs consists of:

- 41 bits for time in milliseconds (gives us 41 years of IDs with a custom epoch)
- 13 bits that represent the logical shard ID
- 10 bits that represent an auto-incrementing sequence, modulus 1024. This means we can generate 1024 IDs, per shard, per millisecond

Let’s walk through an example: let’s say it’s September 9th, 2011, at 5:00pm and our ‘epoch’ begins on January 1st, 2011. There have been 1387263000 milliseconds since the beginning of our epoch, so to start our ID, we fill the left-most 41 bits with this value with a left-shift:

```
id = 1387263000 << (64-41)
```

Next, we take the shard ID for this particular piece of data we’re trying to insert. Let’s say we’re sharding by user ID, and there are 2000 logical shards; if our user ID is 31341, then the shard ID is `31341 % 2000 -> 1341`. We fill the next 13 bits with this value:

```
id |= 1341 << (64-41-13)
```

Finally, we take whatever the next value of our auto-increment sequence (this sequence is unique to each table in each schema) and fill out the remaining bits. Let’s say we’d generated 5,000 IDs for this table already; our next value is 5,001, which we take and mod by 1024 (so it fits in 10 bits) and include it too:

```
id |= (5001 % 1024)
```

We now have our ID, which we can return to the application server using the RETURNING keyword as part of the `INSERT`.

Here’s the PL/PGSQL that accomplishes all this (for an example schema instal):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insta5.next_id(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
    seq_id bigint;
    now_millis bigint;
    shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('insta5.table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;

    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
    result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
    result := result | (shard_id << 10);
    result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And when creating the table, we do:

```
CREATE TABLE insta5.our_table (
    "id" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT insta5.next_id(),
    ...rest of table schema...
)
```

And that’s it! Primary keys that are unique across our application (and as a bonus, contain the shard ID in them for easier mapping).